# Sever.Transfer from ASHX handler, HttpContext.Current.Session is null

Tags: asp.net

So I'm trying to do a `Server.Transfer` from a generic handler to an regular ASPX page.

It transfers okay, but it's finding the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null.

Anyone know why?

Thanks for the help!

-Ev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got to mark handler with [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) marker interface in order to have Session initialized. If you only need to read from session use [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) marker interface, so Session State Provider can skip saving session at the end of request. In case of out of proc Session State Provider that can give some gains in performance.

Here is the example :

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace BlahBlah
{
  public class CustomHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I think the Server.Transfer was a bit of a red herring for me :)